# One of two Lotus Domino servers doesn't display changes I've made

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus-designer

We've got two servers. Both are 8.5.3FP6. I've got the same client Lotus. My problem is that most of the changes I've made haven't displayed on one of the servers. This is our main server, and this app has a replication on the other. And on the second server everything is fine. For example I've made changes in a view. In the selection I have filtered on two columns. Then I want to use this view in a Custom control, but the first server displays it without this filter. The second server displays the custom control with this filter.
I don't know what went wrong, because when I first set the filter, it was displayed, and 5 minutes later when I changed the filter key, nothing has changed on the first server. But it replicated to the other, and on that it is fine.

Comment: I'm having some trouble following this question.  You seem to be saying the data is replicated between servers, but the view is not updated on both servers.  Is that right?  If so, there are ways to control when a view is updated (e.g. View.setAutoUpdate in Java).  I'm not sure that's relevant here, so I suggest you add some sample code to the question.  That might help someone spot the problem.

Comment: It sounds like this is an issue with replication of the design changes to the MAIN server from the OTHER server. The issue could be associated with the ACL of the database, the connection records used to replicate them, the replication settings of the database, or several other possible issues.

Comment: Here is my code for the selection in the view:

SELECT Form = "ProjektmunkaAdatlap":"ProjektMunka" & (Consultant = @Left(@V3UserName; "/") | Consultant = "Dr. "+@Left(@V3UserName; "/") | tutor = @Left(@V3UserName; "/") | tutor = "Dr. "+@Left(@V3UserName; "/"))

It's ok on the second server xpage, but on the main server it's not displayed as it should. But if I remove the "Dr. "+ option, it's fine again on both servers. But this option is very important.

Comment: First: Don't use @V3username, use @Name() instead.   Second: Is this a private view?

Comment: I see now. The view has generated, and then it won't change. On the other server I don't know why was difference between the two view.
Now I filtered the view control, and it works.
Thanks for Your support!

Comment: Use @name([x]; @username) where [x] is the correct namepart to select - but using name-based selections on a view selection on a server is problematic and should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

look at:
1 connection document on server (replication/routing and shedule, source/dest server)
2 rights on db for replication servers
3 on advanced replication options on the db. maby there is unmarked design elements.

all best